# Looking for a strategy for parsing a file

Tags: python, parsing

I'm an experienced C programmer, but a complete python newbie. I'm learning python mostly for fun, and as a first exercise want to parse a text file, extracting the meaningful bits from the fluff, and ending up with a tab-delimited string of those bits in a different order.

I've had a blast plowing through tutorials and documentation and stackoverflow Q&As, merrily splitting strings and reading lines from files and etc. Now I think I'm at the point where I need a few road signs from experienced folks to avoid blind alleys.

Here's one chunk of the text I want to parse (you may recognize this as a McMaster order). The actual file will contain one or more chunks like this.

```
1   92351A603   Lag Screw for Wood, 18-8 Stainless Steel, 5/16" Diameter, 5" Long, packs of 5
Your Part Number: 7218-GYROID
22
packs   today
5.85
per pack     128.70
```

Note that the information is split over several lines in the file. I'd like to end up with a tab-delimited string that looks like this:

```
22\tpacks\tLag Screw for Wood, 18-8 Stainless Steel, 5/16" Diameter, 5" Long, packs of 5\t\t92351A603\t5.85\t\t128.70\t7218-GYROID\n
```

So I need to extract some parts of the string while ignoring others, rearrange them a bit, and re-pack them into a string.

Here's the (very early) code I have at the moment, it reads the file a line at a time, splits each line with delimiters, and I end up with several lists of strings, including a bunch of empty ones where there were double tabs:

```
import sys
import string

def split(delimiters, string, maxsplit=0):
    """Split the given string with the given delimiters (an array of strings)
    This function lifted from stackoverflow in a post by Kos"""
    import re
    regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    return re.split(regexPattern, string, maxsplit)

delimiters = "\t", "\n", "\r", "Your Part Number: "
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(split( delimiters, line))

f.close()
```

Question 1 is basic: how can I remove the empty strings from my lists, then mash all the strings together into one list? In C I'd loop through all the lists, ignoring the empties and sticking the other strings in a new list. But I have a feeling python has a more elegant way to do this sort of thing.

Question 2 is more open ended: what's a robust strategy here? Should I read more than one line at a time in the first place? Make a dictionary, allowing easier re-ordering of the items later?

Sorry for the novel. Thanks for any pointers. And please, stylistic comments are more than welcome, style matters.

Comment: Not sure if you mean one list or one string for question 1, but for one list it'd be `[item for item in lst if item]`.  For one string, you'd just do `'\t'.join(item for item in lst if item)` with `\t` replaced with whatever you wanted to use to join the items.  For question 2, you should really be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  We'd be happy to help you out there :)

Comment: might want to checkout the re module.

Comment: @MattJoyce he's literally using the `re` module in his code.

Comment: hah oops yeah didn't see it because I assumed it'd be at the top with the other imports =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove empty strings by:

```
new_list = filter(None, old_list)
```

Replace the first parameter with a lambda expression that is True for elements you want to keep.  Passing None is equivalent to `lambda x: x`.

You can mash strings together into one string using:

```
a_string = "".join(list_of_strings)
```

If you have several lists (of whatever) and you want to join them together into one list, then:

```
new_list = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, old_list)
```

That will simply concatenate them, but you can use any non-empty string as the separator.

If you're new to Python, then functions like `filter` and `reduce` (**EDIT**: [deprecated](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) in Python 3) may seem a bit alien, but they save a lot of time coding, so it's worth getting to know them.

I think you're on the right track to solving your problem.  I'd do this:

- break up everything into lines
- break the resulting list into smaller list, one list per order
- parse the orders into "something meaningful"
- sort, output the result

Personally, I'd make a class to handle the last two parts (they kind of belong together logically) but you could get by without it.

Comment: Avoid the use of `string` as a variable name.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks, forgot there was a module with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, misha, that helped me get over the next hurdles. I'm using python 3.3, and Guido recommends a for loop instead of reduce, but that's fine, I'm learning to write nice compact readable loops in python, it's a joy.

One issue remains: the file is made of several chunks of text like my posted example, and I'm not sure how to separate them out except to count lines (which doesn't seem very robust). That may, however, be the only choice.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me about the fate of reduce (I didn't know that before).  If you know that each item occupies a fixed number of lines, there's nothing wrong with counting lines to separate items.  Otherwise, you could look for lines that are obviously the start of a new item (or, alternatively, the end of the current item), and perform the split that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `close` file when using `with`.

And if I were to implement this. I might use a big regex to extract parts from each chunk(with `finditer`), and reassemble them for output.